# Как обойти скрипт обнаружения блокировщика рекламы?

Tags: реклама

Я пользуюсь uBlock origin. Скачал скрипт fuckfuckadblock и включил через TamperMonkey. Попробовал зайти на сайт gidonline.club - он обнаружил uBlock и просит его выключить. Как сделать uBlock незаметным для таких страниц? (Пробовал AdBlock на том же сайте - тоже не работает) (Пользуюсь Google Chrome)

Вот ссылка http://gidonline.club/2011/04/luna-2112/, при нажатии на плэй выскакивает баннер.

Comment: способ есть. а где конкретная ссыль, где обнаруживает?

Comment: @EgorRandomize, В тексте вопроса.

Comment: чтобы обойти, надо маскировать баннер под обычную картинку. Или юзать HTML5 баннеры с помощью конвертера swf -> html5 . Обходить можно, вопрос насколько нужно.

Comment: Так а чего TamperMonkey не устраивает? Написали скрипт, который убирает/скрывает блок или сдвигает вбок далеко в сторону, поставили  срабатывание по таймеру и всё

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр: Вроде ж ТС хочет, наоборот, убрать рекламу, а не пропихнуть её.

Comment: @VladD да, верно, спать надо раньше ложиться))

Comment: Дело в том, что подобные плагины неким образом лезут в HTML/CSS/JS код страницы. Соответственно JS код может эти плагины обнаружить, и определённым образом реагировать. Обойти - только писать патч для плагина, думаю. Но мне тоже интересны другие способы обнаружения плагинов - может быть есть более универсальные хаки..

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр: Поскольку плагины получают управление первыми, теоретически они могут зарулить загружаемый с сайта код. На практике это не реализовано, но было бы интересно.

Comment: У меня обычный АдБлок я не вижу вообще никакой рекламы. Я не в теме?

Comment: Странно, настройки не менял, но теперь не вижу никакой рекламы.

Answer (score 1):

Простого пути нет. Есть хардкорные:

1. Изучить код сайта и либо убрать то, на что срабатывает, либо написать JS (расширение), который заставит сайт работать.
2. Можно выключить стандартный список адблока и вручную блокировать только ту рекламу, что действительно вас беспокоит.

Answer (score 0):

Есть скрипты Анти-анти-адблока, вот [один](https://reek.github.io/anti-adblock-killer/) из них, которые отслеживают реакцию сайта на блокировщик рекламы и убирают её (во всяком случае, пытаются).
Тот скрипт, на который я дал ссылку защищает Adblock, Adblock Plus, uBlock Origin и Adguard AdBlocker.